# How can I launch an Internet Explorer process as another user, a la /netonly?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, winapi, pinvoke, ntlm

I'm trying to launch Internet Explorer as another user from our WPF app, so that when our users visit the (internal) website, they silently authenticate via Integrated Windows Authentication.

We do not want to launch iexplore.exe as the other user because of weird deployment/environment issues that occur when you launch a process for the first time on a computer and it attempts to set up IE7/8 for the first time. Though, if you have a solution for how to mute every IE installer on every machine, I'd love to hear it.

Back to my intended question. I'm able to get the exact IE impersonating behavior I want* from the command prompt  using `runas` (thanks to https://serverfault.com/questions/70376/runas-domain-account-still-asks-for-password):

```
c:\> runas /noprofile /netonly /user:MyDomain\MyUser iexplore.exe
```

*note: I can't use `runas` for our WPF app for many reasons, but the *end result* is what I want.

Anyway, I'd like the C# equivalent code that does a `runas /noprofile /netonly iexplore.exe`.

I am halfway there with P/Invoke on `CreateProcessWithLogonW`. This is what I have:

```
uint LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY = 2;
var lpStartupInfo = new CreateProcessWithLogonW_PInvoke.STARTUPINFO();
CreateProcessWithLogonW_PInvoke.PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;

CreateProcessWithLogonW_PInvoke.CreateProcessWithLogonW(
                userName,
                domain,
                pw,
                LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY,
                null,
                commandLine,
                0,
                null,
                null,
                ref lpStartupInfo,
                out processInformation);
```

This successfully launches Internet Explorer, but does not seem to impersonate the user at all. I am able to impersonate the user via the runas command, so I'm 98% sure the failure to authenticate isn't an IE/zone/password/IIS setting, it's just something I'm not doing right in my call to `CreateProcessWithLogonW()`.

One thing I've noticed is that the `runas /netonly` command only works if I add the `/noprofile` switch, which is something that is stumping me. I have no idea how to set the equivalent of this switch via P/Invoke in C#.

Help is appreciated with either solution (solving the "IE runs a wizard when I launch it the first time", or finding the weirdo P/Invoke setting I'm missing).

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with Windows, but why not let the browser launch under the user who is using the app -- my (admittedly not-thought-about-in-a-while) understanding is that it would then just work -- the browser would send the encrypted creds of the logged-in user to the server and only request auth if they failed.

Comment: Oh, I see. The users might be new users who would have to go through the IE setup BS, right? (sorry for reading it wrong the first time through)

Comment: Does this help as a way to preconfigure IE? http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/readyhow-preconfigured-ie7-8-multiple-users-lab-environment

Comment: Given the weirdness (and another problem that happens when IE is already open), I may just try to solve the IE installer issue instead of launching the process "/netonly".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I was very very close. The magic fix is adding `-noframemerging` to the iexplore.exe call, which...honestly I'm not sure what it does, it uses the phrase "process frame" which is awesome and perhaps means something to you.

In any case, this appears to be resolved.

```
var arguments = "-noframemerging " + url;
var pathToIExploreExe = GetFullPathToIExploreExe();
var commandLine = string.Format("\"{0}\" {1}", pathToIExploreExe, arguments);

uint LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY = 2;
var lpStartupInfo = new CreateProcessWithLogonW_PInvoke.STARTUPINFO();
CreateProcessWithLogonW_PInvoke.PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;

CreateProcessWithLogonW_PInvoke.CreateProcessWithLogonW(
            userName,
            domain,
            pw,
            LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY,
            null,
            commandLine,
            0,
            null,
            null,
            ref lpStartupInfo,
            out processInformation);
```

Comment: for an explanation of that `-noframemerging` actually does see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/28/ie8-and-reliability.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN... starting with IE 8 it means the same as `-nomerge` in previous IE versions...

Answer (score 0):

[CreateProcessWithLogonW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) requires that the specified user account must be allowed to log on interactively. Could it be a problem? Try [CreateProcessAsUser function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if that works.

Comment: I'm okay with the interactive process requirement. I just read the CreateProcessAsUser documentation and it looks like I would effectively be creating a process with the new user (interactive or not), which would create the profile and run the IE7/8/9 first run wizard, which brings me back to my problem.

Comment: Just an observation. You don't need to use `CreateProcessWithLogonW` in C# as the [`Process.Start` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx) calls it internally if the UserName and Password properties of the StartInfo instance are set.

Comment: I don't think you understand the significance of `LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY`, which is something only `CreateProcessWithLogonW` does.